# Cannot Create Java Web Application in Apache NetBeans 16

Tags: java, netbeans, web-applications, ide, netbeans-16

'Java Web' categories doesn't exist in *New Project Categories* in Apache NetBeans therefore, I cannot create Java Web Application using Netbeans.  How do I resolve this Issue?

[image]

[image]

Even though I can create Java Web Application with maven or Gradle the folders structures are different from the tutorials that I am watching. To solve this issue I went to tools-->plugins and in there I have activated Java Web and EE. But still I cannot see the 'Java Web' in Apache Netbeans Categories.

Comment: If your tutorial is not using Maven or Gradle, you may benefit from finding a more modern tutorial. The web world and Jakarta EE (formerly Java EE) have evolved significantly.

Comment: You ae correct I am watching from archive.  The reason I am watching is because I just need to understand JSP and SERVLET thats all

Comment: (A) Very well then. The basics of Servlet and JSP have not changed. (B) I inlined your screenshots for you.

Comment: Is **File > New Project... > Java with Ant > Java Web > Web Application** what you are looking for? But that will create an Ant project. As Basil suggests, you might be better off with tutorials that use Maven or Gradle. If you are still stuck update your question with links to the tutorials you are using.

Comment: @skomisa Yes, I am still stuck. However, I am going to take heed from your suggestions. I am going to learn it from modern tutorials. Do you have any tutorials on Udemy or from other sources where they teach Java Web Application using Gradle? I found some, but they only teach the tool Gradle or Maven. FYI, the tutorial I am using is from 2015, I think, and it is in a different language.